# Why did Charles Lamb write his brother’s name as John L---?

Tags: essays, charles-lamb

In the 9th paragraph (according to the version I’m reading) of Charles’ Lamb’s essay “Dream Children: A Reverie” it is written

> I told how, though their great-grandmother Field loved all her grand-children, yet in an especial manner she might be said to love their uncle, John L ---

Why is ‘Lamb’ not written fully? Why three hyphens? Is it done by the publishers or the author himself?